# Controller invoking another controller C# WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller, it needs to invoke another controller.  We WERE doing this work on the client.  We want to do this server side for performance reasons.

Request is a POST
Request Url = "http://example.com/api/foo/1234567  (pretty standard url with binding for an id)

Request Data

```
{
  something1:'abc',
  something2:'def',
  copyFromUrl : '/api/bar/7654321'

};
```

The copyFromUrl could be any other controller in the application.  I don't want to hand jam a bunch of if statements up and down the stack to do the binding.

Complicating the issue is most controllers have three different GET signatures.
Get(sting id)
Get(sting id, string xpath)
Get()

Comment: In the same application you don't need invoke entire http stack. You can call your controller like you call any other class. `MyController controller = new Mycontroller(); MyReturnType ret = controller.Get(id);`

Comment: In my application that would require hundreds of if statements.  if url.contains("/api/foo") then( if query.segemnts = 2 ... and so on. The routing engine already has all this logic.

Comment: May be your application is not designed well? Or may be it is not designed for that. You really should be able to call any controller in a regular .net manner. I feel your app doesn't have good `single responsibility`

Comment: I am facing the same issue. @EricRohlfs, were you able to find a good solution for this?

Comment: I was not able to resolve this issue is WebApi1. Version 2 may have something.

Comment: @T.S. I think the singe responsibility you are referring to is the ability to re-invoke the routing engine to resolve to the appropriate controller constructor and method.  This is more about efficiency than bad design.  Many frameworks support the ability to issue multiple commands at one time.  Why make two http calls when one can do the job. Howto in WebApi is not straight forward.

Comment: I read-over again what was written here and I think, based on your statement `that would require hundreds of if statements`, I think you need IOC container. And you definitely don't need to make http call from one controlled to another.

Comment: If you know the method for the call in `copyFromUrl` why can't you just use an [Http Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to make the call?

Comment: @boosts I can't remember the details, but I think we had some issue with this, either firewall or local system restriction.  There is always the performance hit.  I've seen some code that can unit test routes in webapi 1.  I was thinking the answer might come from dissecting that capability.

Comment: i have a question, would it require auth key every time calling this api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this, would be to basically short-circuit HttpServer and HttpClient classes. I am using here ASP.NET Web API 2, but hopefully same technique can be used with original Web API.

Here is the minimalistic working sample:

```
public class BarController : ApiController
{

    // GET http://localhost/api/bar
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {"Foo Bar", "Progress Bar"};
    }

    // GET http://localhost/api/bar?bar=Towel Bar
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetCustomBar(string bar)
    {
        return new string[] {"Foo Bar", "Progress Bar", bar};
    }

    // POST http://localhost/api/bar?action=/api/bar?bar=Towel Bar
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage StartAction(string action)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        var server = new HttpServer(config);
        var client = new HttpClient(server);
        var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost/" + action).Result;
        return response;
    }
```

As you can see here, the first two actions differ in parameters, the third action accepts url (as in code example) that allows it to invoke any other action.

We are basically hosting a server in memory, applying same routes our real server has, and then immediately querying it.

Hard-coded `localhost` is actually not used run-time, the routes ignore it, but we need valid absolute URL name for the internal validation to pass.

This code is just an illustration, proof-of-concept if you may.