# How to invoke one controller method from another given only the uri

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

for simplicity consider a person resource such as

```
{"name":"Fred Flintston",
"worksAt":
   {"href":"api/sites?cn=Slate%20Rock%20and%20Gravel%20Company"}
}
```

When I receive this on the POST to the PeopleController I need to get the site resource from the worksAt.href.

What I would like to do is invoke the correct GET on the SitesController leveraging the routing engine that already knows how to parse the uri and invoke the correct method.

I have seen one suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155691/81514) which seems rather heavy handed, and I'm not at all sure how that would allow the authorization that has already happened to carry through.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following, but if you describe in detail what you want to achieve, we might be able to find a better solution.  It is MVC based, but should work for web API too.

```
var baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));
var requestUrl = new Uri(baseUrl + "Home/Index?i=42");

//get method info
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("/", requestUrl.AbsoluteUri, ""), new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())));
var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext));
var controllerType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + "Controller");
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType) as ControllerBase);
var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType);
var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());
var methodInfo = (actionDescriptor as ReflectedActionDescriptor).MethodInfo;

//parse the query string
var qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(requestUrl.Query);
//and use the only item in it as an int when calling the action
var ret = methodInfo.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType), new object[] { int.Parse(qscoll[0]) });
```

The parameter passing is now baked in, so you'd need to create a correctly ordered parameter array, based on the parameter names, and types.

Comment: Is it possible to get an array of parameters extracted from the request in the way the method expects them dynamically? e.g. [FromBody] object, string id, [FromUri] cn etc.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you do it with an action filter, for a clean and generic solution, 
you can use the reroute attribute when ever you want to pass the href property in the response and reroute the user to a different action.

```
public class RerouteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContextb actionExecutedContext)
        {
           // using the code of Tamas above me to invoke the action 
           var response = ((ObjectContent)(actionExecutedContext.Response.Content)).Value.Href;
           //get method info
          var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("/", response.AbsoluteUri, ""), new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())));
          var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext));
          var controllerType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + "Controller");
          var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType) as ControllerBase);
          var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType);
          var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());
          var methodInfo = (actionDescriptor as ReflectedActionDescriptor).MethodInfo;

          //parse the query string
          var qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(requestUrl.Query);
          //and use the only item in it as an int when calling the action
          var ret = methodInfo.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType), new object[] { int.Parse(qscoll[0]) });

        }
    }
```

food for thought, why do you need to do this ? 
maybe your app architecture is not correct,
consider this - instead of making a call to a different action in some controller, why dont you call a method in some service outside the controller which can do the work that needs to be done?
this requires you to put you're core logic outside of the controllers and inside Logic services which holds the core business logic of your application, 
using explicitly in a function inside some service is much simpler elegant and clear to the viewer.

i recommend you read about the principle of -lean controller, fat models, and 3 tier architectures in software development,

good luck.

Comment: There's nothing in the original post that would suggest that the controllers are "fat".  The issue is that the API consumer needs to pass a reference to a resource and that there are few different ways that could be expressed.  Consider you as a resource in my system. I could reference you by some primary key, your DL, your email address.  The routing engine knows how to match the URI to the specific code that will find the resource.